# Busybox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash) enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

Tags: root, busybox, ash

initramfs appears on the screen, my computer is just cli, it does not login.
I have tried some commands, but it does not work.

There is more

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root fsck.ext4 -a -CO  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan list found. This is the error message:

> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options)

I did this, but `fsck` did not work. It exited with

> status code 4 done.
>   Failure File system check of the root filesystem failed
>   The root filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root requires a manual fsck
>
> BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
>   Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repair your file system...

**Either:**

At the initramfs prompt:

- type `fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`

**Or:**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode
- open the `terminal` app
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it worked!

Comment: I tried `fsck -f dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` since that's what path autocompletion worked with, just adding here that you have to do it as the answer suggests, don't use the autocompletion! Thanks for the answer, worked for me!

Comment: Thanks a million heynnema!
I encountered this same problem after a hard shutdown, and this command got me back up and running.

Comment: Don't know how to thank you. Thanks a lot.